# Linking a Kivy Button to Function on Builder

Tags: python, kivymd

I want to attach a button on the screen to a function, but each time an error is displayed below

> AttributeError: 'MDFlatButton' object has no attribute 'plus_drive'

This is a help file that includes stringing pages

```
screen_helper = """
    Screen:
        canvas:
            
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [25, 0, 0, 0]
        ScreenManager:
            clearcolor:[0, 1, 0, 1]
            MenuScreen:
            ransomwareScreen:
            keyScreen:
        
        
    <MenuScreen>:
        name:'menu'
    
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
    
            MDToolbar:
                title: "Title"
               
    
            MDBoxLayout:
    
                MDNavigationRail:
                    id: rail
                    use_resizeable: True
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "comment-account"
                        text: "profile"
                        
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "security"
                        text: "security"
                        on_touch_up : root.manager.current = 'ransomware'
    
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "folder-key"
                        text: "folder-key"
                        on_press : root.manager.current = 'key_file'    
    
    
    <ransomwareScreen>:
        name: 'ransomware'
        
        MDList:   
            OneLineListItem:
                text : "item"
        MDFlatButton:
            text : "salam"
            pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .1}
            on_release : self.plus_drive        
    
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
    
            MDToolbar:
                title: "demo"
    
            MDBoxLayout:
    
                MDNavigationRail:
                    id: rail
                    use_resizeable: True
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "comment-account"
                        text: "profile"
                        on_release : root.manager.current = 'menu'
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "security"
                        text: "security"
                        on_release : root.manager.current = 'ransomware'
                        
    
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "folder-key"
                        text: "folder-key"
                        on_release : root.manager.current = 'key_file'  
    
    
    
    <keyScreen>:
        name: 'key_file'
        OneLineListItem:
            id : "drive"
    
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
    
            MDToolbar:
                title: "demo"
    
            MDBoxLayout:
    
                MDNavigationRail:
                    id: rail
                    use_resizeable: True
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "comment-account"
                        text: "profile"
                        on_release : root.manager.current = 'menu'
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "security"
                        text: "security"
                        on_release : root.manager.current = 'ransomware'
    
    
                    MDNavigationRailItem:
                        icon: "folder-key"
                        text: "folder-key"
                        on_release : root.manager.current = 'key_file'   
    
    """
```

and my code to run the app:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from helper import *

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ransomwareScreen(Screen):

    def plus_drive(self , obj):
        print("salam")
        return

class keyScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(ransomwareScreen(name='ransomware'))
sm.add_widget(keyScreen(name='key_file'))

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen


DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: Could you please show us how are you adding the MD button? I mean what is the function you are doing to add that button or have you already added that button on the kivy lang section? Or are you trying to add that button dinamically and have a function attached to that button?

Comment: Try using ```app.plus_drive()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MDFlatButton:
    text : "salam" 
    pos_hint: {"center_x": .9, "center_y": .1}
    on_release : app.plus_drive()
```

Since you are calling to a function in the app